# how to build APK for Android intended for internal distribution?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on an Android app with React Native.

For testing and developing I just follow the regular dev workflow with a server on my dev machine, reload JS, etc.

Now I want to pass the APK to other people in my company so that they can test the app on their device.

I've been looking into the `android` folder on my React Native project but I can't find an APK ready to send to other people. It seems the only APK was built when I created the project a few weeks ago, and I'm assuming this APK does not contain any JS code.

I've found [these instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) for building a signed app for the Play Store, but I don't need to distribute this APK on the Play Store.

So, how do I create a self contained APK with the JS files and assets that I can easily pass to other people for testing?

Comment: `gradle assemble` should make an APK file in `project/build/outputs/apk/`

Comment: how do I run that command? I keep getting `-bash: gradle: command not found`

Comment: Thanks I already figured it out. It is indeed `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: @cricket_007 do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link you already had in the question, you can skip over the signing details, and just go to "Generating the release APK"

> Simply run the following in a terminal:
>
> `$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`
>
> Gradle's assembleRelease will bundle all the JavaScript needed to run your app into the APK.
>
> ...
>
> The generated APK can be found under `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`, and is **ready to be distributed**.

Comment: As a follow up... do you know how I can change the file name of the apk which now is `app-release-unsigned.apk`?

Comment: That's just what gradle names it, so I'm not sure if there is a way. You could just append a new command onto that one, though. `&& cp app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk ./YourNameHere.apk` and that'll copy the file to the current directory